# CakePHP Containable doesn't return correct results in "has many" relation

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

Someone can tell me why it doesn't work:

```
$data = $this->Question->find('all', array(
                             'conditions' => array(
                                               'Question.id' => $qid
                                             ),
                             'contain' => array(
                                            'Slide' => array('Training')
                                          )
                   ));
```

Relation is as follows:

`Training -> has_many -> Slide -> has_many -> Question`

So Why result is something like that:

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [Question] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
            )
        [Slide] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1320
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling #find on the Question model.  So, you need to define the relationships from Question to Slide and from Slide to Training to include them in your results.  Try adding Question belongsTo Slide and Slide belongsTo Training.

Comment: I defined those relationships at the begining, when I created all models, so it's not the solution.

Comment: Can you edit your question and include your model code and a more complete dump of the result?